# Memcached server with multiple webservers

Tags: centos, memcached

I'm struggling for days now, I'm setting up my cloud infrastructure: 
1 nginx Loadbalancer
2 Centos Webservers
1 Centos Memcached server

On the webservers I've installed the php-pecl-memcached packages and made the necessary adjustments to php.ini. The webservers connect to the memcached server over a private network:

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "10.xx.xx.xx:11211"
```

The webservers are capable of connecting, tested it with `telnet 10.xx.xx.xx 11211` and the memcached server is able to output the statistics when you type stats.

Now trying to check if Memcached works as it should results in a PHP error:

```
HP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (memcached). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0, referer: https://example.com
```

It looks like the session.save_path as mentioned above isn't used, while it should be accessible, see telnet test.

Comment: Did you edit the correct php.ini?

Comment: Yes, see the first code block

Comment: The code block doesn't answer my question. Remember that Ubuntu has several php.ini files; you must edit the correct one.

Comment: Ohkay, that maken sense. The webservers run on CentOs 6.5 and the /etc/php.ini has been adjusted. On the 'dedicated' memcached server there is no PHP installed.

Comment: You tagged your question `ubuntu`. That makes things very confusing when you aren't actually using it! I've removed this tag.

Comment: Michael, the memcached server is running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Seemed that there was another config file overriding the php.ini settings. Check the `/etc/php.d/` folder for a `memcached.ini` file. Override the settings in this file.